# Asp.net web api routing to be like mvc site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

How can I add a route so that my controllers will work similar to a mvc web appliation.

Because the default way that they have configured the routes will end up with you having so many controllers.

I just want to have a controller called Auth,

and then in my web API be able to call `api/auth/login`  or `api/auth/logout` etc.
Because with the default routing I will have to create a controller for login and one for logout.

So then I would have my Controller like so:

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> Login()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpMessageHandler Logout()
    {
        return new HttpMessageHandler.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default Web API route uses the http method to determine the action to select. For example `POST api/auth` would look for an action named `Post` on `AuthController`.

If you want to use RPC style routing (like MVC) you need to change the default route to:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Now `POST api/auth/login` will look for an action named `Login` on `AuthController`.

Comment: Then do i just specify the Get, POST, etc as a filter type as in mvc?

Comment: You can't do HTTP method based routing in MVC, you have to specify the action name. You use the `[HttpGet/HttpPost]` filters to *constrain* the type of requests that the Action can handle not whether it will actually match the route.

Comment: So then How do I specify in the controller if it will be a get or Post? see my edit

Comment: Ok, but then how would I have a controller called login that can service a GET and a POST . Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is the default behaviour or Web API (not what you're asking in your question). Create a new `LoginController` with actions `Get/Post`. Please start a new post if your question has changed, rather than changing your current one.

Comment: I have not changed the question.  What I am askign is if i have controller called Auth:  I cannot have two action methods with the same name. So I cant have  public void login [httpGet] and public void login [httpPost]

Comment: Am I doing something silly here? What / How does one normally use the web api?